# ¿Se pueden enviar 2 parametros en ng-show, angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

En una vista tengo 2 div. Al inicio debe verse uno pero cuando le de click a un boton este se debe ocultar y mostrar el segundo div que al inicio esta oculto.

Primer div que al inicio debe mostrarse

```
<div class="md-card-content" ng-controller="solicitudcomprasCtrl as showCase" ng-show="formVisibility">
</div>
```

Segundo div que al inicio esta oculto

```
<div id="div_agregarProducto" ng-show="agregarProducto">
</div>
```

Aca el boton

```
<a ng-show="formVisibility" ng-click="showCase.edit(showCase.item[' + data.id + '])"><i class="md-icon material-icons md-bg-teal-900 uk-text-contrast">&#xE32A;</i></a>
```

Por el momento puedo ocultar el div "formVisibility" siendo este el primer div, de esta manera accediento a la funcion edit:

```
$scope.formVisibility     = true;
$scope.agregarProducto    = false;

              function edit(item){
              console.log("Ocultar Div");
              $scope.agregarProducto    = true;
              $scope.formVisibility     = false;
              $scope.item = item;  
            }
```

Pero no puedo hacer que se muestre el segundo div que es el "agregarProducto" ya que esta accion la debe hacer con el mismo boton, que otra solucion podria aplicar

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta utilizar la misma variable para ambos. Solo que una esperando un true y la otra un false. Es decir en html:

Div 1:

```
<div class="md-card-content" ng-controller="solicitudcomprasCtrl as showCase" ng-show="formVisibility">
</div>
```

Div 2:

```
<div id="div_agregarProducto" ng-show="!formVisibility">
</div>
```

Controlador:

```
$scope.formVisibility     = true;

              function edit(item){
             $scope.formVisibility = !$scope.formVisibility;  
            }
```

Mira si así te queda solucionado.

Comment: El Div 2, al inicio aparece lo cual debe estar oculto, pero al dar click al boton se oculta el Div 1 y asi si funciona porque se queda el Div 2. Como debo ocultar al inicio el Div 2. Gracias.

Comment: Ya me funciono, muchas gracias. tenia mal ubicados los div y el controlador.

Comment: Podrías contestar con la solución y dartela como solucionada para ayudar en el futuro a otros que lo necesiten?